# Is it possible to execute exact code segment using a separate JVM at Java run-time?

Tags: java, jvm

I am working on an automation project where I need to start the automating java application using a separate JVM in each test case. I am thinking of launching new JVMs before each testcase is executed. And then, execute the test case within that created JVM. Is it possible to do so.

I have tried [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), [`Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)  and [`Apache ANT`](https://ant.apache.org/). In these approaches, we can provide a class name and make the class executes in a separate JVM. So the providing class should have a main method in it. But not exact code segments.

AM I missing something here ? Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: You can generate a class with a `main` method which executes the desired code. Or use a testing framework which already has that feature…

Answer (score 0):

What test frameworks do is have a class with a main memory which can call any method in an instance of a class loaded via reflection. e.g.

Call a static method without args in any other class.

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String className = args[0];
        String methodName = args[1];
        Class.forName(className).getDeclaredMethod(methodName).invoke(null);
    }
}
```

Call `java -cp . Runner AnyClass anyPublicStaticMethod` and you don't need a `main` to run that method.